# How to know which triangle contribute to the color of a pixel?

Tags: graphics, directx

I'm total new in graphics and DX, encountered a problem and no one around me know graphics too. Sorry if the question seems too naive.

I use DirectX 11 to render a mesh, and I want to get a buffer for each pixel. This buffer should store a linked-list (or some other structure) of all triangles that contribute color to this pixel.

Should I operate on which shader or which part of DX? Or simply, where could I get the triangle information in pixel shader?

Comment: The simple answer will be: add ID to your vertex attributes (each vertex in triangle should have the same value - 'polygon id' so that they won't change during interpolation) and pass them through vertex shader to pixel shader where you can use it, if you need to.

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes or something that you need at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the triangle ID in the pixel shader but using the hardware z-buffer you can only capture one triangle per pixel.

With multisampled textures you can capture more triangles. This should be enough in practical situations.

If your triangles are extremely small and many of them are visible within one pixel then you should consider the [A-Buffer](http://amddevcentral.com/afds/assets/presentations/2041_final.pdf) with your own hidden surface removal algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need it only for debug purposes** you can use any of graphics debuggers:

1. Visual Studio Graphics Debugger (integrated since Visual Studio 2012)
2. For AMD GPUs: [GPUPerfStudio](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-perfstudio-2/)
3. For NVidia GPUs: [Nsight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html)
4. Good old PIX from DX SDK.

**If you need it at runtime** (BTW, why? =) )

- Use [System-Generated Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#PrimitiveID): `VertexID`, `PrimitiveID` and `SV_VertexID` to calculate exact primitive or even vertex, that contributed in pixel color. It is tricky, but possible.
- Another way is to use some kind of custom triangle ID in vertex declaration. But be aware of culling.
- You can output final data from pixel shader into [buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then read from it on CPU.
- All of such problems are pretty advanced topics in DirectX. I'm not sure if "total new in graphics and DX" coder can solve it.